# Swift Project Doesn't Recognize CocoaPod Library

Tags: swift, cocoapods, baasbox

I created a Page-based project and immediately created a Podfile in the root of the project with the following content:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'BaasBoxSDK', '~> 0.9'
```

I then ran `pod install` via terminal and opened the new workspace. Thanks to `use_frameworks!` it's my understanding I should be able to use the library without creating and setting up bridged headers. I have tried with and without bridged headers and XCode doesn't seem to detect my library or classes from the library. Am I missing a step? (this is my first Swift project).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you calling

```
import BaasBoxSDK
```

in the files you want to use it in

Comment: Looks like that builds, but AppCode must be buggy. Autocomplete does not work, but at least in XCode it shows up.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're missing `import BaasBoxSDK` line in the files you want to use it. Also, after adding a library, run project once so that library will get compiled and class suggestion will be available in Xcode.